# InDesign Text Modification Script Skips Paragraphs

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

The following InDesign (Java)script does not change the text content and formatting of all paragraphs:-

```
for (var j = 0; j < app.activeDocument.stories.length; j++) {    
    for (var k = 0; k < app.activeDocument.stories.item(j).paragraphs.length; k++) {
        var myText = app.activeDocument.stories.item(j).paragraphs.item(k);
        myText.contents = C2Unic(myText.contents, myText.appliedFont.fontFamily);
        myText.appliedFont = app.fonts.item("Mangal");
        myText.pointSize = myText.pointSize*0.878;
        myText.composer="Adobe World-Ready Paragraph Composer";
    }
}
```

In the image below note the content with pink background. All those have source formatting. What is happening?

[image]

Comment: Could it be applying a font that doesn't exist on your system?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Both the source and target fonts are present as the correctly converted portions with white background show.

Comment: Could it be that the text in paragraphs with problems has more than one font or font size?

Comment: Thanks for the observation. Let me check that.

Comment: @JoshVoigts's comment also applies if you set your font to bold and italic text, where you do not have those variants. Run your script and see what InDesign believes to be applied to the pink text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the solution, but sometimes it helps to loop backwards through paragraphs when you are modifying `contents`.

```
for (var j = 0; j < app.activeDocument.stories.length; j++) {    
    for (var k = app.activeDocument.stories.item(j).paragraphs.length; k--; ) {
        var myText = app.activeDocument.stories.item(j).paragraphs.item(k);
        myText.contents = C2Unic(myText.contents, myText.appliedFont.fontFamily);
        myText.appliedFont = app.fonts.item("Mangal");
        myText.pointSize = myText.pointSize*0.878;
        myText.composer="Adobe World-Ready Paragraph Composer";
    }
}
```